# I can't translate embedded mongoid models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, mongoid, locale

Setting model is embedded in partner model. Partner model attributes are translated but setting model attributes aren't. I tried

```
en:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      partner:
        name: "Name"
        company_name: "Company"
        setting:
          prefix: "Prefix!"
          suffix: "Suffix!"
```

and

```
en:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      partner:
        name: "Name"
        company_name: "Company"
      setting:
        prefix: "Prefix!"
        suffix: "Suffix!"
```

Both don't work.

How can I translate setting model attributes?

Thanks panmari.
Those are using in the view file. I want "s.label :prefix" show "Prefix!" in the result.

```
= form_for @partner do |f|
  table.table
    tr
      td
       = f.label :name
       = f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control"
      td
       = f.label :company_name
       = f.text_field :company_name, :class => "form-control"
    = f.fields_for :setting do |s|
      tr
        td
         = s.label :prefix
         = s.text_field :prefix, :class => "form-control"
        td
         = s.label :suffix
         = s.text_field :suffix, :class => "form-control"

  .card-footer
    = button_tag :type => "submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary-outline     btn-block' do
      i.fa.fa-check-circle.fa-lg
      |&nbsp;Submit
```

Now I tried below and it doesn't work either

```
en:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      partner:
        name: "Name"
        company_name: "Company"
        settings:
          prefix: "Prefix!"
          suffix: "Suffix!"
```

I reverted to "setting" in locale file and I customized error view. Then I got this error. So it doesn't work still but plural "settings" seems right.

```
I18n::InvalidPluralizationData in PartnersController#create
translation data {:prefix=>"Prefix!", :suffix=>"Suffix!"} can not be used with :count => 1
```

Error view is below just in case.

```
- if @partner.errors.any?
  - if @partner.errors.messages[:setting]
    - @partner.errors.messages.delete(:setting)
  .alert.alert-danger style="text-align:center"
    button.close type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
      span aria-hidden="true"
        i.fa.fa-times.fa-lg.text-danger
      span.sr-only
        |Close
    div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;"
      i.fa.fa-exclamation-circle.fa-lg
      - if @partner.setting.errors.any?
        |&nbsp;#{@partner.errors.count+@partner.setting.errors.count}
      - else
        |&nbsp;#{@partner.errors.count}
      ul
        - @partner.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li style="min-width:10rem;" = message
        - if @partner.setting.errors.any?
          - @partner.setting.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            li style="min-width:10rem;" = message
```

Comment: How are you trying to display these translation? Give an example where you use it and what you'd expect as output.

Comment: Did you try the first version, but with using the plural `settings`?